# How can i get a product key for Openfeint in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk, openfeint

I am trying to open Game Network sample codes from Corona sample codes. I tried to open OFlandscape and it gave me this error :

To use OpenFeint in your game, you need to get a product key and product secret. This can be done on the OpenFeint website.

However i couldn't find it. Can you help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not what you asked, but OpenFeint is now obsolete on Corona, and will be removed or replaced (it is in their [roadmap](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/roadmap/) this).